# Can input parameters be transformed into xml structure?

Tags: xslt, xslt-1.0

I need to transform input paramater string like "1-410000 54-420987 63-32000" into the structure (like below) inside xslt to use its data later in xslt:

```
<config:categories>
  <category>
    <value>410000</value>
    <label>1</label>
  </category>
  <category>
    <value>420987</value>
    <label>54</label>
  </category>
  <category>
    <value>32000</value>
    <label>63</label>
  </category>
</config:categories>
```

P.S.
Are there any other options to parse string like "1-410000 54-420987 63-32000" in order to use its data in xslt to extract the right part (after the '-') if the left part is found in input document?

Comment: It is better to pass the document as a parameter. Of course it is possible to generate this in XSLT, too, but the former is recommended.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**This transformation**:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
 xmlns:config="some:config" exclude-result-prefixes="config">
 <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes"/>
 <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

 <xsl:param name="pData" select="'1-410000 54-420987 63-32000'"/>

 <xsl:template match="/*">
     <config:categories>
       <xsl:call-template name="gen"/>
     </config:categories>
 </xsl:template>

 <xsl:template name="gen">
  <xsl:param name="pGen" select="$pData"/>

  <xsl:if test="$pGen">
   <xsl:variable name="vChunk" select=
    "substring-before(concat($pGen, ' '), ' ')"/>
      <category>
        <value><xsl:value-of select="substring-after($vChunk,'-')"/></value>
        <label><xsl:value-of select="substring-before($vChunk,'-')"/></label>
      </category>
      <xsl:call-template name="gen">
       <xsl:with-param name="pGen" select="substring-after($pGen, ' ')"/>
      </xsl:call-template>
  </xsl:if>
 </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**when applied on any XML document (not used), produces the wanted, correct result**:

```
<config:categories xmlns:config="some:config">
   <category>
      <value>410000</value>
      <label>1</label>
   </category>
   <category>
      <value>420987</value>
      <label>54</label>
   </category>
   <category>
      <value>32000</value>
      <label>63</label>
   </category>
</config:categories>
```

**Explanation**:

Proper use of **[`substring-before()`](http://www.w3.org/TR/xpath/#function-substring-before)** and **[`substring-after()`](http://www.w3.org/TR/xpath/#function-substring-after)** plus recursion.

Answer (score 2):

As Dimitre shows, parsing strings in XSLT 1.0 is quite cumbersome. This is an area where XSLT 2.0 is far superior. It can be done like this:

```
<categories>
  <xsl:for-each select="tokenize($param, '\s+')">
    <category>
      <label><xsl:value-of select="substring-after(., '-')"/></label>
      <value><xsl:value-of select="substring-before(., '-')"/></value>
    </category>
  </xsl:for-each>
</categories>
```

And of course in XSLT 2.0 you can then use the categories structure as a first-class node value without having to use the node-set() extension to get inside it.

Answer (score 0):

to make XML from a string I think you have to use Java. I am not aware of an XSLT functioniality to achieve that.

For your second question:
There is substring(), string-length(), substring-before() and substring-after() that might help with your request.
Please refer: http://www.w3schools.com/xpath/xpath_functions.asp

Comment: If you're using Java, then you have XSLT 2.0 available, and converting this string to XML in XSLT 2.0 is much easier than doing it in Java.